# Simulating a logarithmic spiral galaxy in python

Tags: python, numpy, random, galaxy, spiral

I am simulating a logarithmic spiral galaxy using python. Using the parametric equations,

`x= a*exp(b*theta)*cos(theta)`
and
 `y= a*exp(b*theta)*sin(theta)`

I used numpy.random for getting the random distribution of stars. The sample code is given below.

```
import random
from math import *
from pylab import *
import numpy as np

n=100000
a= 1
b=0.6
th =np.random.randn(n)
x= a*exp(b*th)*cos(th)
y=a*exp(b*th)*sin(th)
x1 = a*exp(b*(th))*cos(th+ pi)
y1=a*exp(b*(th))*sin(th + pi)
plot(x,y,"*")
plot(x1, y1,"*")
show()
```

The resulting image is shown below
[spiral galaxy with two arms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXQKU.png)

What I need:
1) stars should be radially distributed in the spiral galaxy. I got the distribution only along the arms.
2) Both arms should be blue. Here I have one arm with blue color and other with green.

After simulating this, I need to rotate the galaxy. Any help regarding this would be appreciable.

**edit: I got both the arms in blue color using `plot(x1, y1,"b*")`

Comment: As for the color: `plot(x1, y1, "b*")` will plot blue stars. If you only specify `"*"` it will change color for several plots. As for the other questions: What have you tried? Show us your failed attempts and we can help your from there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It works. Actually I am out of idea. I don't know how to radially distribute the points(stars) as we see in a galaxy. @mwormser

Comment: You're using the wrong model - you'll never get "radial noise" using this model. You could try adding gaussian noise to `x`, `y`, `x1` and `y1`, and it'll give you _something_. But whether or not that's enough for your purposes isn't clear. If you're trying to make a pretty picture, then it doesn't matter. If you're trying to simulate some astrophysics, then it's probably not what you want. Maybe you should try asking on physics.stackexchange?

Comment: Thank you. I am simulating this for an astrophysics project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an approximation is good enough, try adding some noise the points before plotting them. For starters I would start with a [normal (Gaussian) distribution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html). For example, this tweaked version:

```
import random
from math import *
from pylab import *
import numpy as np

n=1000
a=0.5
b=0.6
th=np.random.randn(n)
x=a*exp(b*th)*cos(th)
y=a*exp(b*th)*sin(th)
x1=a*exp(b*(th))*cos(th+pi)
y1=a*exp(b*(th))*sin(th+pi)

sx=np.random.normal(0, a*0.25, n)
sy=np.random.normal(0, a*0.25, n)
plot(x+sy,y+sx,"*")
plot(x1+sx, y1+sy,"*")

show()
```

Gives this output:[image]
You might need to play around with the variables a bit to adjust the output to your needs. Also, as mentioned in the comments, this isn't true radial noise.

Comment: can I get a distribution like this? @Pikalek    https://s32.postimg.org/69f3oliz9/hqdefault.jpg

Comment: potentially - I've updated my answer with example code & an output image

Answer (score 1):

To rotate the image, I would calculate the new positions of the stars using a rotation matrix, which you have to do for each star like

```
R = [ [ np.cos(phi), -np.sin(phi) ], [ np.sin(phi), np.cos(phi) ] ]
[x_new, y_new] = np.dot( [x_old, y_old], R )
```

What exactly do you mean with "radially distributed"? Could you draw an example image?

Comment: See this galaxy image.. I want a distribution like this. What I get is only along the arm.@RobertAlpha    https://s32.postimg.org/69f3oliz9/hqdefault.jpg